# Why are PNG-8 files mangled when opened in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, image-editing

Why are some 32 bit PNGs opened in Photoshop with Indexed Colors and no transparency?

For instance, I grabbed a png icon file of the Stack Overflow logo at: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/icon-so.png  When opening it in Photoshop CS3, it apparently treats it as **indexed color and gets rid of the alpha channel**.  The image on the right is a screen grab of the icon.  Changing the Image mode in Photoshop to RGB doesn't change the image at all.  I've tried this with a few other PNGs and it seems hit or miss.

When viewed in other programs, it displays fine.

left:png opened in Photoshop, right:screen grab of png from browser

[image: left:png opened in Photoshop, right:screen grab of png from browser]

What gives?, does Photoshop not interpret the PNG file format correctly?

Comment: you can open this png in http://pixlr.com/editor/ and save, resulting png can be opened in photoshop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that **Photoshop doesn't support part of the PNG-8 standard**.  PNG-8 like GIF uses a 256 color pallet.  Both formats support using one of those 256 indexed colors to represent transparency, **PNG-8 also supports setting an alpha-value for each of those 256 colors** on the pallete.  Photoshop (apparently CS3 and CS4) doesn't support this and renders every pixel opaque.

Comment: Indeed, see http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/09/18/png8-the-clear-winner/: “I can certainly confirm that none of PhotoShop, Gimp, Paintshop Pro, or Xara has this functionality [PNG8 alpha transparency] built-in.”

Comment: Updated URL for that article: [PNG8 – The Clear Winner](http://www.sitepoint.com/png8-the-clear-winner/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (in Photoshop CC):

`Image -> Mode -> Check "RGB Color"` (Not *Indexed Color*)

The file will now be editable as usual.

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of PNG files in common use. PNG8 uses indexed colors and has a single color for transparency, which means no alpha channel. PNG24 supports a separate alpha channel. The image you link to is a PNG8.

As for why Photoshop CS3 is mauling PNG8s so badly... that I don't know.

Comment: Photoshop CS4 is no better either, though Fireworks CS4 opens it perfectly. No clue what gives.

Comment: I guess it's good to know I'm not just doing something wrong :-)