# Photoshop does not open PNG with grayscale colors correctly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are PNG-8 files mangled when opened in Photoshop?](https://superuser.com/questions/151662/why-are-png-8-files-mangled-when-opened-in-photoshop)

I'm trying to use Adobe Photoshop CS5 to edit a PNG image. It contains grayscale colors, but Photoshop shows only two colors.

When Photoshop opens the image, it shows only transparent and gray colors, making all icons ugly. The image is displayed correctly in browsers and in other image viewers.

Here's the image - PNG resource with icons:

[image]

The image was likely png-crushed. Photoshop shows "Indexed Color" mode and Color table contains multiple spots with the same color.

If I try to save the image back, it is ruined - saved as it is shown in Photoshop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the image you have posted the link to the original?  I see it as just grey icons on a clear background in Firefox.

Comment: @matt-jenkins Yes, it is, you're seeing it correctly. You won't if you open this image in Photoshop.