# Convert compressed PNG-8 back to PNG-24

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, png

I have a PNG-8 image with transparency, which, due to [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/151662/why-are-png-8-files-mangled-when-opened-in-photoshop), I cannot edit in Photoshop (CS5).

Is there a tool that would convert PNG-8 back to PNG-24, preserving transparency layer, so that the file will open correctly in Photoshop?

(The other way to deal with that problem would be to capture a screenshot of any browser displaying that PNG-8 file correctly - but then it would be necessary to induce the transparency layer back, which I'm not sure how is done.)

[Sample of PNG-8 image](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any specific tool for that purpose, but I do know that with GIMP you can open the PNG8 and change the colorspace using the menu path Image->Mode->RGB. Unfortunately I do not have Photoshop to test if the new file is openable myself, however I've provided a version of the sample you provided where the colorspace has been changed so you can give it a try.

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6Ad3OCQFyOINmMyOGE0ZmEtMDhjOC00OTZmLWE4M2EtYTYzZmJlZjMyNTA0

Comment: Needed this exact same file... thx from the future! ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Photoshop displays transparency wrong: You've got PNG8 with alpha not supported by Photoshop. For editing, keep PNG in 24-bit, and convert to PNG8+alpha only when done. **You can convert PNG8 to 24-bit by resaving it in Preview.app**, Fireworks or with:
>   pngout -s1 -c6 -force file.png

The answer comes from http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/png-that-works/ under the troubleshooting heading.

I also created a YouTube video to show the process at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCO37zYhEp0.

Comment: Thanks, Nick - already re-saved with GIMP from the above answer, but pngout may be a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a scriptable/command line solution:

After installing GDAL Python Tools (on Linux `apt-get install python-gdal`)

```
pct2rgb.py -of PNG -rgba PNG8.png PNG24.png
```

Comment: The installation command no longer works on Ubuntu 20.4